# How to generate a HTML table dynamically from a nested JSON object using ngRepeat directive of AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, angularjs

I have to create a table as follows from a nested object.

JSON object :

```
{
    "A":{
        "1":"X",
        "2":"Y",
        "3":"Z"
    },
    "B":{
        "1":"P",
        "2":"Q",
        "3":"R"
    }
}
```

Desired Table :

```
A: X|Y|Z
B: P|Q|R
```

HTML code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
<body>

    <div ng-controller="GreetingController" >
        <div ng-repeat='(key,val) in arr'>{{temp(val)}} 
            <div ng-repeat='(nestedKey,nestedVal) in aux'>  
                {{nestedVal}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.arr={"A":{"1":"X","2":"Y","3",},"B":{"1":"P","2":"Q"}};
        $scope.temp = function(val)
        {
            console.log(val);
            $scope.aux = val;
        }
    }]);
</script>
```

I am unable to understand how and where to place the `<table>`,`<tr>` and `<td>` tags to be able to generate the table as describe.

Comment: look at what he is doing http://vanderwijk.info/blog/nesting-ng-repeat-start/ you can use that and just apply your json

Comment: Likely to get confusing later on by assigning  a variable name like  `arr` ,which somewhat implies `array`, to an object that isn't an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

`tr` is row and `td` is table cell

```
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
<body>
    <div ng-controller="GreetingController" >
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat='(key,val) in arr'>
                <td>
                    {{key}} 
                </td>
                <td ng-repeat='(nestedKey,nestedVal) in val'>  
                    {{nestedVal}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @Dubby this works fine if you fix the invalid syntax in data shown in the controller code  http://plnkr.co/edit/MqKkoqxeSvp1hKkHcHBm

Comment: if I need to wrap the table, ie after 5 images it shifts to the next row, how can that be done?

Comment: You shouldn't try to do this with table. Table is for strict rows and columns numbers. If you want to make more flexible layout you can try div or flexbox

Answer (score -1):

```
<div ng-controller="GreetingController" >
   <table>   
      <tr>
          <td><div ng-repeat='(key,val) in arr'>{{temp(val)}} </td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td> <div ng-repeat='(nestedKey,nestedVal) in aux'> </td> 
                 {{nestedVal}}
             </div>
      </tr>
        </div>
  </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't generate the kind of table as mentioned in the question